# How can I wait for Mono to finish so I can utilise generated value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, webclient, spring5

I want to return the status code from the sendRequest() method instead of just being able to print the value. Could anyone please point out how to modify the code below, to `"wait for the Mono to complete"`?

I know I can use `Thread.sleep(1000);` but this really does not seem to be a good approach!

```
private fun sendRequest(url:String): Disposable {
    val webClient= WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url.trim())
            .defaultHeaders { header: HttpHeaders ->
                header.setBasicAuth("username", "password") }
            .build();

    return webClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .exchange()
            .map { response: ClientResponse -> response.statusCode() }
            .subscribe { v -> printStatus(v)}
}

fun printStatus(statusMono: HttpStatus) {
    println(statusMono)
}
```

I know that since I am using WebClient in a Webflux application I must return the Mono or Flux all the way out to the calling client, since it is the calling client that is the subscriber. But I cant find out how.

Comment: I don't really understand the question but why don't you just do:  return webClient.get().uri(url).exchange().map { it.statusCode() } ?

Comment: Thank you. What the question is meant to say is "How can I get the status code of the request". I dont need the response body. Just the status code

Comment: I have tried the way you are suggesting but then I cant read the value inside the Mono. It would have to be         return webClient.get().uri(url).exchange().map { it.statusCode() }.block()            but I dont want to use block() because I need to keep the code reactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@JEY` posted the answer above.
This worked for me:

```
webClient.get().uri(url).exchange().map { it.statusCode() }
```